# HTML5 Load Mp3 From Google Drive IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm coding small app get a playlist from google drive
`"http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=$id"`

But in ios can't play it.In desktop normal operation. I can't debug in ios. I do not know what to do. Anyone experienced in this matter does

[My website error](http://vintagerose.vn/testwp/2017/10/26/test-mp3/)